# C# - WireShark detects incomming packets but application does not receive them

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, wireshark

I've got a strange problem. I have a client sending packets to my server, but my servers UDP socket never receives them. Same thing happens the other way around, if I send and he tries to receive.

Check this image, captured from wireshark:
http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/2636/bokus.png

I hav bound my UDP socket to EndPoint 192.168.2.3, which is the internal IP of the server, and port 9998.
The client sends data to my IP, which should then be forwarded to the local server machine..
As you can see wireshark clearly detects incomming packets for 192.168.2.3 with destination port 9998 but nothing gets delivered!

(...why does it say distinct32 btw in destination port?)

Comment: Your question gives no clue what might be wrong. There is probably a bug in your code.

Comment: I don't know what could possibly be wrong; the UDP socket binds to  the correct EndPoint and receivesFrom from the right EndPoint. receiveFrom callback is never ever triggered, and I have idea why this might be. What could affect this other than wrong EndPoints (which I know are correct)?

Comment: To your last question: because that's the (inofficial) service that typically uses this port: http://ports.my-addr.com/tcp_port_list-udp_port_list_search_by_number.php?filter=on&protocol=UDP&ports_list=9709-10010

Comment: Did you check for a firewall dropping the data before it reaches your application?

Comment: UDP/TCP port 9998 is used by the "distinct32" service or application. I can't find any information about what it actually is. It would be like Wireshark replacing TCP port 25 with "smtp".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something else to watch for is make sure any firewall you might running has a rule setup to allow communications on your port 9998.

If I had to guess (would need to see your recieving C# code to know), It looks like you might be trying to receive UDP packets but using TCP protocol on the client side. (Or i might just be misunderstanding some of the text of your screenshot.)

Theres no need to 'listen' for a connection when using UDP.  UDP packets don't have a connect/disconnect protocol.  Nor do they guarantee that packets are received in the same order they're sent.

try using something along these lines in your C# client and see if you get data.

```
var udpClient = new System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient(9998);
Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
```

Comment: Hello, No its not working :(  I have no idea why it dosn't, TCP works fine but not UDP.